# Push datas from Ionic 3 to Laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel, typescript, ionic-framework

I have to send some data from my app Ionic 3 to my back-end in Laravel 5.4 via an API.

My datas are like that :

```
{"item1":"stuff","item2":"stuff2"}
```

Here is some code i made to send this to the API, but i don't know how to send "this.newBird" to to "addData()"

```
export class SaveBirdPage {

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public serviceOne: BirdService) {
      this.serviceOne.addData().subscribe(
            data=> console.log(data)
      );
  }

  newBird= {}
  addBirdForm() {
      console.log(JSON.stringify(this.newBird));
      return(this.newBird);
  }
```

Thanks for your help !!

Comment: you could use HTTP to do this!

Comment: more reference https://baljeetsingh.in/blog/build-an-app-with-ionic-framework-and-laravel-602/